# ld: library not found for -lfftw3l

Tags: c++, cmake, build, link

Пытаюсь собрать проект с помощью cmake, cmake файл:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13)
project(project LANGUAGES C CXX)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS OFF)
find_package(FFTW3l)
find_package(GSL)
find_package(MPI COMPONENTS C CXX)

add_executable(exec
  file1.cxx
  file1.h
  file2.cxx)

target_link_libraries(exec
    PRIVATE
    fftw3l
    GSL
    MPI::MPI_C
    MPI::MPI_CXX)
```

После того как делаю make получаю ошибку: ld: library not found for -lfftw3l
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) (если fftw3 убрать, то получаю соответственно для gsl). Система macOs Catalina. Если компилировать один файл сразу с помощью g++, то все работает, если указывать -lfftw3 -lgsl. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Дык может вместо `fftw3l GSL` сделать `fftw3 gsl`?

Comment: Это я тоже пробовал, не помогает. Как я понимаю, с регистром тут проблем никаких нет